# Which tool can I use (as a tester) to track the code coverage for a web based application?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, tools, coverage

I am a QA Intern and we use Selenium Webdriver to test our web based application. We are provided with a server on which the build to be tested is deployed. I wish to know is there a tool that I can use to track the code that is being covered by the tests that are run on that particular server?
Also, keeping aside Selenium, in general, how can I track the code coverage of the application? 
I know about ScriptCover, does that help to track the coverage of entire UI or just the javascript part of it?
Please Help. Thanks

Comment: In what programming language is the back-end developed in?

Comment: You can use Intanbul for this. You can refer below link. https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41705/code-coverage-for-selenium-tests/

Answer (score 1):

Scriptcover is Javascript only.

List of code coverage tools: 
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CodeCoverageTools 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329/what-is-your-favourite-code-coverage-tools-free-and-non-free

This article summarizes how-to and how-not-to use code coverage:
http://www.exampler.com/testing-com/writings/coverage.pdf

Other related and useful answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051563/how-do-code-coverage-tools-work 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455046/how-do-code-coverage-tools-work-in-different-languages?rq=1
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90002/what-is-a-reasonable-code-coverage-for-unit-tests-and-why?rq=1